# slideshow JSNI?

Tags: jquery, jsni

I have a file jQuery about slideshow effect.I want to use JSNI and nothing happens. I don't know where is wrong. Can anybody help me? This is my native function

```
public native void slideshow() /*-{
$(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 5000});
    });
         }-*/;ter code here
```

Comment: please provide some more details, such as relevant code snippets, error messages or anything that can help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is JSNI in GWT, you need to address the window using $wnd instead of $(window).

Comment: I'm not sure how GWT JSNI handles jQuery selector syntactic sugar. Try using a regular javascript class selector instead of $